# Display OpenAPI 3.0 YAML file in Spring Boot (Maven)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-3, swagger-ui, openapi

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but none of my searches have gotten me the answer I was hoping/looking for.

**Problem Statement**
I'm writing a Spring Boot application which exposes a bunch of RESTful API's. For various reasons I have a YAML file that contains the API documentation (written in OpenAPI 3.0). I'm looking for an *easy* (it's Spring Boot after all) way to show that document.

**What I've done**
Spent more then 3 hours reading various posts, watching youtube vids that talk about Springfox's swagger and swagger-ui (amongst other things)

*This generates the documentation 'on the fly', I want to display the YAML file*

I've seen a couple of posts that discuss downloading the swagger-ui github repo, unzip it and modify the index.html to point at my YAML file instead of the default it has.
 *While this is doable, it requires me to manual download, update files and repackage them (not a huge issue but seems more then I would expect)*

**Solution being looked for**
Ideally I was hoping there was a Maven plugin that I could setup and pass a config option to, telling it where the YAML file is located and it would *simply display it*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can serve the file as a static resource, either by adding it to one of the spring boot default static resources locations (src/main/resources/META-INF/resources, src/main/resources/resources, src/main/resources/static, src/main/resources/public) or by overriding default locations and add your custom path where your open-api yaml file is located (set spring.resources.static-locations property).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than changing the location of the static resources, you can copy the file to one of the standard locations using Maven (or whatever build tool you use). I'm using OpenAPI Generator to generate source code from the spec and also using it to generate an HTML view of the spec.

I copy that file to a static resource location during the build, too. I haven't figured out an easy way to get the Swagger UI working, though. The HTML view was a compromise.